# Does the potential energy for a given photon increase or decrease in quanta?

Tags: gravity, photons, energy-conservation

As a photon leaves a strong gravitational field, it loses energy and redshifts. Is the exchange in potential energy of a photon characterized by energy quanta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A photon of a given frequency $f$ *is* exactly one quantum of energy. An electromagnetic wave has a total energy given by $E_\text{total} = \langle N\rangle hf$, where $\langle N\rangle$ is the number of photons in the wave.

When an EM wave escapes from a gravitational potential well (or falls into one), it's the energy of each individual photon that changes; in other words, the unit in which energy is quantized gets smaller or larger. The number of units (number of photons) stays the same.

Comment: This doesn't feel completely satisfactory. One can imagine that interaction between two "gravitationally charged" objects happens by exchange of gravitons in the very same way that interaction between electrically charged objects happens by exchange of photons.

Comment: @Marek: hm, okay, good point. In true quantum gravity, I suppose the frequency changes might be quantized. But I don't know that we have a well-accepted way of calculating that quantization, and I think my answer is valid as long as you keep GR classical.

Comment: @David: sure, in classical GR it's fine. As for that true quantum gravity: string theory would be a bit overkill here, I think :) Just quantize linearized GR on a Schwarzschild background.

Comment: what I meant was, is the given frequency of a photon recognized as a value that can take any value such that there is no minimum discrete increment in which the energy of a photon can be gained or lost?

Comment: @HAL: well, that question is hard to answer. Currently our theories are based on particle exchange and energy can be transferred continuously in this picture (because the intermediate particles can have any energy too). Nevertheless, it might be that for some reason this picture is modified and energy will be discrete at very small scales. In any case, one would need full quantum gravity as David said.

Comment: @Marek: My understanding is that the photon-graviton diagram is divergent at the tree level if you just quantize linearlized gravity.  The gravity-matter couplings are worse than the gravitational self-coupling.

Comment: @Jerry: to be honest, I am not familiar with this stuff all that much but I thought it works because people are using it for various applications. Is the divergence in any sense essential (i.e. worse than usual divergences in QFT)?

Comment: @Marek:  I know that there are ways to deal with it, but my knowledge about the back-reaction stuff in semi-classical gravity is pretty limited.  I"m pretty sure that the only sense in which these divergences are worse than QFT one sis the fact that the underlying theory is non-renormalizable, so the divergences get worse at higher and higher order.