# What is the age of the Universe from the big-bang light perspective?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light, universe, reference-frames

What is the age of the Universe from the big-bang light perspective?

We all agree that the universe is around 14 billion years, from the perspective of a hypothetical observer moving in a galaxy, e.g. ourselves.

But what would be the age of the universe from the perspective of the first light that emerged from the big bang, given that it has been traveling at the absolute $c$ speed of light?

Comment: Maybe 380000 years younger? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background

Comment: At lightspeed, time is not a meaningful concept.

Comment: Or if you prefer, the answer is zero, since proper time approaches zero as the observer's speed approaches $c$. Though, since those photons weren't emitted right at the big bang itself, you could also say the answer is 380,000 years, which is the age of the universe at the time of photon decoupling. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background.)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29082/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Lengths of time are not well-defined for objects moving at $c$ in Einstein's theories of relativity. That is to say, light cannot attribute age to anything.