# Is any photon really moving?

Tags: special-relativity, photons

I read that when something moves at the speed of light, length contracts at the direction of motion. Now consider a photon traveling in the z axis. Since it is travelling at the speed of light, the z axis space should shrink to zero length. If there is no space in z direction how can the photon move? Also, for the photon is the universe a 2D plane( If only 3 dimensions exist in this universe)?

Comment: Duplicate of [Would time freeze if you could travel at the speed of light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29082/50583) There is no frame of reference for the photon, so "the z axis space should shrink to zero" is a meaningless statement.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Could you please provide me an alternate link which explains why the photon doesn't have a frame of reference. The PSE link is not helpful.

Comment: And anyone reading this question please provide helpful links as comments before this question gets closed. :)

Comment: See also [Does a photon in vacuum have a rest frame?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16018/50583)

Comment: (1) Comments aren't the place for answering the question (2) I don't think this is a duplicate of the one listed in the first comment because that is asking about time, whereas this is asking about space.