# If you hit the light barrier what would it look like?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames, observers

Is it correct to say that if you hit the speed of light you would travel at the same speed as a single image in time would?  And if you were to (if possible) travel faster than light, you would theoretically be travelling faster than than the images that have already come by. It is a known fact that when we are looking at stars billions of light years away we are essentially looking into the past. If you were travelling faster than the speed of light (without the argument of relativity) would your perspective turn to something like an image looking down two mirrors adjacent to one another but moving through each image- what we perceive as time but going backward.  I am no mathematician or physicist just an average person pretty much no math and physics education,  but a vivid imagination. Degrading comments are unnecessary I'm just curious.

Comment: Related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29082/

Comment: Pretty much, yes; given neither of those things are possible under relativity.

Comment: @Countto10 that should be flagged as a duplicate

Comment: Sorry I didn't know there was an question similar.  I have only joined a few hours ago still working out the site

Comment: On the current physics it is impossible -> you can imagine anything. If you near $c$, the cosmical microwave background will be stronger and stronger. At 0.9c, the interstellar gas (around 1 atom / cubic cm) is enough to bake you.

Comment: I think I could reformulate your question which would make it reopened with a good chance. But I will do it only for your ask. It requires a significant upgrade.

Comment: Yes I understand all of the impossibilities of the question and no living thing could travel so fast and live or still be in one piece.  how would you reformulate the question?  what do you mean after you said this??  Only do it for my ask?

Comment: DilithiumMatrix could you possibly Un duplicate this post as I don't think it is asking the same question in respects

Comment: There is no Light barrier.  You cannot even approach the speed of light as an absolute.  You can't even move relative to light--you can only move relative to other (non-light) objects.  You can certainly move 99.995% the speed of light relative to other objects--in fact you currently are moving at that speed--but I'm not sure what that gets you.  There are interesting questions but they involve acceleration and maybe the speed of the propagation of light--not so much the speed of light itself.