# Does time slow down for light according to relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, spacetime, speed-of-light, time

According to Einstein's theory of relativity
Time slows for a individual who moves at the speed of light and time goes backward if the individual is faster than the speed of light.

So , is it that for light. Time slows down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would time freeze if you could travel at the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29082/)

Comment: Note that time does not go backwards at speeds faster than $c$. It is possible to travel backwards in time if you can travel faster than the speed of light, but it involves quite a complicated manoeuvre.

Comment: Ok. My question is closed because its similar to some other one. but my question is a bit different. I ask if for individual , he experience going backwards or time slowing down. Does thr light also experience anything ? What if light itself travelled faster than it's original speed of light. What would light experience

Comment: @John Rennie sir

Comment: Hi srijan Sri. Welcome to Phys.SE. To reopen this post (v3) consider to stress in post why it is different from suggested duplicate.